# directive not working inside <tr> that is ng-repeat bound

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table where the rows are repeated via `ng-repeat`.
I am trying to create a template that generates columns `<td>` for each row `<tr>`

```js
app.directive("customtd", function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: "<td>{{position.Name}}</td><td>{{position.Code}}</td>",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      position: '='
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="p in positions">
    <customtd position="p"></customtd>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The issue is my custom td template is not rendered at all.
Here I intend to replace `<customtd>` with n number of `<td>`s - which will be decided based on number of properties on my data object, but at the moment I am just trying to get a simple directive working that will output two columns.

[MYPLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/tHv9LQMlQcLimSx2GKmM?p=preview) : shows an instance of this issue and the directive code.

Comment: if you look at the console it is throwing an error saying `Template must have exactly one root element. was: <td>{{position.Name}}</td><td>{{position.Code}}</td>`

Comment: now the question is whether the table row has any other columns than the one provided by the `customtd` directive...

Comment: The template that you use for a directive should have single root element. Since in your case there are multiple `td` hence the error. I don't see a way where you can wrap your `td` elements inside a root element, as the only parent allowed is `tr`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in comments the template of a directive should have single root element. So I would suggest you to move the `tr` element to the template of the directive, like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/YjLEDSGVipuKTqC2i4Ng?p=preview

Comment: thanks that worked I was kind of disappointed to see the directives with type 'Element' nested in ng-repeat do not make much use. your solution worked. I extended it to display headers by looking the keys on data object. http://plnkr.co/edit/BEi7an1yhvc4pMgRNTAt?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

As Pavlo wrote, you can move the `tr` element to the template for the directive. Another option is to use a `td` element and directive that replaces your `td` with the template that you want to use.

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="p in positions">
    <td replace-me template="mytemplate.html" position="p"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Directive `replaceMe`**

```
.directive("replaceMe", ["$compile", '$http', '$templateCache', function ($compile, $http, $templateCache) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
               position: "="
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                function getTemplate(template) {
                    $http.get(template, {cache: $templateCache}).success(function (templateContent) {
                        element.replaceWith($compile(templateContent)(scope));
                    });
                }
                scope.$watch(attrs.template, function () {
                    if (attrs.template) {
                        getTemplate(attrs.template);
                    }
                });


            }
        }
    }]);
```

**mytemplate.html**

```
<td>{{position.Name}}</td>
<td>{{position.Code}}</td>
<td another-my-directive></td>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KUSnwlUvnqv3t7Pw9Qm9?p=preview)