# Adding a table row after last row created with ng-repeat not working

Tags: angularjs

The following does not add a table row but just adds a label into the table. Any ideas why?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rows" create-table>
                <td nowrap ng-repeat="value in row">{{value}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [], function () {
})

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.rows = [{
        title: 'One'
    }]
})

app.directive('createTable', function () {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last){
            // console.log(element[0]); - table row
            angular.element(element[0]).after(
                "<tr><td><label>Two</label></td></tr>"
            );
        }
    };
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K9ENF/27/)

If you inspect the table element you will see this:
[image]

Comment: Did you try with a border on? "<table border="1">"

Comment: Is it related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426279/directive-not-working-inside-tr-that-is-ng-repeat-bound ?

Answer (score 4):

Is there a particular reason that you're trying to do this with a directive?

If not you could do something like this: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v27R4/

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat-start="row in rows">
                <td nowrap ng-repeat="value in row">{{value}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="$last">
                <td><label>Two</label></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Additional info on ng-repeat-[start/end] is here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat

Note: CSS in fiddle is just to show that it is in the actual table

Comment: +1 Even though this doesn't answer the question exactly it pointed me to a way of doing it differently. I now just hard code the extra row in the HTML and use the directive controller to handle any callbacks. Thanks.