# How to include html file in directive angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In index.html

```
<li nav-popup-url="popover.tpl.html" nav-popup-width="400" nav-popup-trigger="click" nav-popup> List 1 </li>
```

In navPopup.js

```
angular.module('navPopup',[])
.directive('navPopup',['$document','$compile', function($document,$compile){

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function(scope, element, attr){

            if(attr.navPopupTrigger == "click"){
                $document.on('click', handler);
            }

            function handler(event){

                if(!element[0].contains(event.target)){
                }else{
                    var template = angular.element("<div style='background-color:red'><br/></div>");
                    var navPopupurl = attr.navPopupUrl;

                    console.log(attr.navPopupUrl);
                    var $popup = $compile(template)(scope);
                    template.remove();
                    $document.find('body').append($popup);

                }

            }

        }

    }

}]);
```

Currently, in navPopup.js as above, I was using an internal html element.

```
var template = angular.element("<div style='background-color:red'><br/></div>");
```

How to change this line of code to make it include an external html file as specify in index.html(nav-popup-url="popover.tpl.html") which contain `"<div style='background-color:red'><br/></div>"`?

Comment: Not sure if it work but try, `scope.myVariable = attr.navPopupUrl` and then  `<div style='background-color:red'>{{myVariable}}<br/></div>` or you can define isolated scope `{ navPopupUrl: '=' }` and then `<div style='background-color:red'>{{navPopupUrl}}<br/></div>`

Comment: Hi, szapio, I'm trying to include an html file which contain <div style='background-color:red'>"+attr.navPopupUrl+"<br/></div>, do you have any ideas on how to include the html file in directive link section?

Comment: You can use $compile service in link function and replace your element with compiled template. I'v got an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426279/directive-not-working-inside-tr-that-is-ng-repeat-bound/28047775#28047775, my directive replace-me, it's not what you asking for but the idea is similiar, i'm passing template as argument but you can define your template inside a link function, and directive replace your tag with your template